# urllib.request.FancyURLOpener is deprecated, what is better method?

Tags: python, urllib, fancyurlopener

I have been using urllib.request.FancyURLOpener() to retrieve images from URLs. My code is something like this:

```
class MyOpener(FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11"

myopener = MyOpener()

myopener.retrieve(source_url, saved_img_path)
```

However, when I instantiate a MyOpener() object, I get the following warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: MyOpener style of invoking requests is deprecated. Use newer urlopen functions/methods
```

What method(s) should I be using instead?